# Input string was not in a correct format? but it is

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

My code is doing what I want from it except it shows an error "Input string was not in a correct format" for this line: `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", Convert.ToDecimal(cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString()))`

here I will provide a little more code so it will be understandable that what I doing:

```vb
Private Sub cboISBN_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboISBN.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        If (cboISBN.SelectedIndex <> -1) Then
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT isbn FROM book WHERE isbn =@isbn", cn)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", Convert.ToDecimal(cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString()))
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT no_of_books FROM book WHERE isbn =@isbn", cn)
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", Convert.ToDecimal(cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString()))
                dt = New DataTable
                da.Fill(dt)
                TxtNo_of_Books.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("no_of_books")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Not Completed Because OF The Following Error " & "%" & ex.Message & "%", "Error", _
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The value I am providing is numeric not string and please don't ask that why I used decimal for ISBN[my choice ;-) ]. last thing I just not came here to post my question and get the answer for it, I am GOOGLING since 2 days and did not find a place to solve my problem!

Comment: The way to debug this is to check the value of `cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString()` at the time when the exception is thrown. You believe it is numeric but the `ToDecimal` method has determined that it isn't.

Comment: So... if value of `cboISBN.SelectedValue` is Decimal, why you need to do `toString/Convert`? Just try pass `cboISBN.SelectedValue` or `CType(cboISBN.SelectedValue, Decimal)` And what is the data type of column in DB?

Comment: There is your issue - your DB datatype doesn't match. For time being try to pass value using `Convert.ToInt32` and see what happens

Comment: Convert.ToInt64 will be better if you are going to try, since number is large for int 32.

Comment: The database doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem, the exception is complaining about an invalid **String** and is being thrown by `Convert.ToDecimal`.

Comment: is this only happening specifically with this isbn value? If so, double check to ensure that you did not type a Letter O for one or more the the Zero's

Comment: Can you please add stack trace to question? Also the type for cboISBN.SelectedValue. I guess it's a combobox and SelectedValue is string.

Comment: @Hazmat I mean the stack trace of the exception. While debugging, an exception is breaking your code right? There you will see exception details and stack trace within it. That way we can see which methods are called to get to this point.. But I'm suspicious about the value you have pasted, I guess when exception occours, the value is empty string, since *Convert.ToDecimal("".ToString())* will throw same eception.

Comment: The only other thing I know to try without the ability to look over your shoulder is to put in a Debug.Writeline("value='" & cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString & "'") and then paste the result from the output window here. This way we can see for certain exactly what is being passed to the parameter. You should be able to put this right before the first da=  line. This is the only sure way we would know what is in that object. After all, you could have forgotten to set the ValueMember for the combobox and we're just assuming you did that part right.

Comment: This is what I was suspecting all along  -`cboISBN.seclectedvalue` is not decimal even that you said it was. You have bound combo box. What you need to do is to get a value from the row. `DirectCast(cboISBN.seclectedvalue, DataRowView).Item("Field_Name")`. Only then you will get to actual value

Comment: Sounds like you stored objects in the CBO.  Of course storing an ISBN as a number of ill-advised to start.  Also, why run 2 queries and get 2 DataTables when a Join would get you everything you need at once?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Comment: @Plutonix. I'm not even sure a join is necessary. I would think the second query would be all that is needed. It would either return a result for no_of_books or would return no row. All of which could be covered after that query is ran with an if statement. If rows.count = 0 then 0 books otherwise use the value received in the field from the query.

Comment: @CharlesMay Yes, `"SELECT isbn FROM book WHERE isbn =@isbn"` is a nonsense query.

Comment: The name of the field in the table (to which your CBO is bound -bound to table?- ) and in which (field) the value resides

Comment: I still have to go back to my suspicion that a ValueMember property hasn't been set. I would really like to know the exact value being passed into the Convert.

Comment: Now everything goes backwards. So, what if you remove all casts and converts, etc. What if you only use `cboISBN.SelectedValue` there? Have you done that? Now, may be you sometimes get decimal and other times null or dbnull?

Comment: `If cboISBN.SelectedIndex <> -1 AndAlso NOt DbNull.Value.Equals(cboISBN.SelectedValue)` . . .

Comment: I believe now you're dealing with problem I mentioned before. Try this - instead of `cboISBN.SelectedValue` use `CLong(cboISBN.SelectedValue)` - lets eliminate that your not matching db type is not an issue

Comment: Sonny - `CLng`. Next  - Lets do this - `Dim v As Decimal =cboISBN.SelectedValue` and then place that `v` where currently you have `cboISBN.SelectedValue`

Comment: Just do this logic and see what happens `Dim v As Decimal =cboISBN.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To really get the `SelectedValue` not the value already loaded in the form which  I set `cboISBN.selectedIndex = -1`we have to change `combobox_SelectedIndexChanged` to `combobox_SelectionChangeCommitted`event of combobox and then it will work smoothly without giving any error. for more clarification see below code as a sample:

```
Private Sub cboISBN_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboISBN.SelectionChangeCommitted
        Dim v As Decimal = cboISBN.SelectedValue
        If (cboISBN.SelectedIndex <> -1) Then
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT isbn, no_of_books FROM book WHERE isbn =@isbn", cn)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", v)
            dt = New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                TxtNo_of_Books.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("no_of_books")
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

decimal.Parse has an overload to define number style.

You can use Any, to handle everything. (e.g. Thousands seperator, whitespaces etc)

```
Convert.ToDecimal(cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString(), 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any)
```

Second problem may be your thread is running in different culture than de other thread/application wich converted decimal to string.
For example in Turkey, decimal and thousands seperator chars are vice versa.

If you have a dot in decimal seperator and comma in thousands, you can use Invariant Culture on parsing like below:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString(), 
    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: The OP believes that the input string is "1000000000002", No separators involved.

Comment: Right, my answer was before I saw the number.. But even tho, I think using InvariantCulture on both sides (Converting to string before this method and back to decimal in this method) is a better habit, even for integers.